# Que significa int mapped int32 o int32 mapped int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

Ando viendo unos tutoriales y dicen siempre esas dos palabras, alguien me puede explicar a que se refiere con mapped? , he buscado por diccionarios(wordreference.com) entre otros y no logro entender a que se refieren.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El tipo `int` es un alias del tipo `Int32` predefinido del espacio de nombres `System`. Puedes ver la tabla de equivalencias (o mapeos) en [Tabla de tipos integrados (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)